# Things that I can compare between QDK and Qiskit

Tags: programming, qiskit, q#

I am planning to write an article which compares QDK and Qiskit

Mainly talking about the different interfaces, and difference in running few algorithms

What all parameters should I compare and take into account, Would love some suggestions

Comment: Q# is the programming language that the Microsoft QDK uses. So the comparison should actually be QDK vs Qiskit and/or Q# vs Python

Answer (score 1):

I think you should take all these things into account:

- How to create a circuit and measurement in both QDK and Qiskit?
- How to apply quantum algorithm in both QDK and Qiskit?
- What are the backends that can be linked to by QDK and Qiskit?
- Special features between those two (Qiskit pulse, Azure quantum, ...)
- Performance between these two
- Any restrictions?

Comment: Available learning material, how easy it is to get started and support would also be an option, depending on who should be targeted in the article :)